# How can I use a variable set on a different method?

Tags: java, swing

In my code, the variable "targetNumber" can't be accessed on a different method. How do I make it possible?
In the method "jButton3Action...", I set the variable. And in the method "jButton1Action..." I try to call it, but it's returning an error:

> Cannot find symbol
>   Symbol: variable targetNumber
>   location: class ggui

```
public static int randInt(int min, int max){
    Random rand = new Random();

    int targetNumber = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

    return targetNumber;
}
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    final int targetNumber = randInt(1, 10000);
}
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    String tooHigh = "Too High!";
    String tooLow = "Too Low!";
    String gotIt = "Got it!";
    int guess;
    guess = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());

    if (!(guess == targetNumber)){
        guess = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
        if(guess > targetNumber){
            resultField.setText(String.valueOf(tooHigh));
        }
        else if(guess < targetNumber){
            resultField.setText(String.valueOf(tooLow));
        }

    }
    else{
        resultField.setText(String.valueOf(gotIt));
    }
```

Comment: Make it a field instead.

Comment: Would that still let it be a random integer generator?

Comment: Yes, why wouldn't it? It just changes the scope in which the variable resides, so it can be used across different methods.

Comment: @JornVernee Thank you, I will try it and reply back if I encounter any other problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having to mess around with scope, instead make the variable a private field of the class, so all methods can access it. This is convenient for all methods, and will remove unnecessary code. Use it like this:

```
private int targetNumber;
```

In `private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {` do this:

```
targetNumber = randInt(1, 10000);
```

In the rest of your program, the code should perform as expected.
Also, don't call the variable in `randint()`: `targetNumber`, because the compiler may get confused as to which one you are referring to in the return statement.

Comment: `private final int targetNumber;` Making the field `final` will result in a compilation error unless it is initialized, and a final field cannot be reassigned (as would be the case in the `ActionListener`)